# Can't modify numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I got stuck practising with images in Python 3:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.image import imread
photo_data = imread('c:\jpeg.jpg')
photo_data[0,0,1] = 0
```

I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f19579124b68> in <module>()
      1 photo = photo_data
      2 print(type(photo))
----> 3 photo[0,0,1] = 0
      4 plt.imshow(photo_data)

ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

I'm following an online course where this code seems working, can you tell me what I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue at hand is that the array is set by `matplotlib` to read-only. To confirm:

```
print(photo_data.flags)
```

And you will get:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : False
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

To make it writable, simply:

```
photo_data.setflags(write=1)
photo_data[0,0,1] = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

some times, you will get error as below if you try to set write flag to True.

`ValueError: cannot set WRITEABLE flag to True of this array`

Just make copy of it and work. it is useful instead downgrading the `numpy` version

`photo = photo_data.copy()
print(type(photo))
photo[0,0,1] = 0
plt.imshow(photo_data)`